# How do I give other players money in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Every time I go to **Quick Menu > Inventory > Cash > Give Cash** it says that I'm unable to give someone else cash.

I know you can only give $5000 each day, but I can't give anything.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I have read on other forums that the option is currently disabled because of 'hackers' with a ton of money were handing out cash to people. I know before the last patch I was able to give cash using this method.

Comment: Last night when I was playing a friend of mine gave me 30% of the bounty when I helped him take someone down in via a helicopter I was flying.... So unless they JUST disabled this, it should still be an active feature - but I am unsure about the limit

Comment: @ZeroStack Sharing cash from the last job is not the feature in question, if that is what you are referring to

Comment: Oh, I dont have the ability to accept bounty missions on other players yet (I have yet to talk to Lester online)... My friends just handed it to me so I thought it would be in the same realm.  My apologies if I am referring to a different feature.

Comment: @Sharlike He was talking about killing someone with a bounty on them, not a job.  You can kill people with a bounty on them from day 1.  You just can't *put* a bounty on someone until you hear from Lester.

Comment: @Archer Well, holding up a store also isn't a 'job', but you can still select "Share cash from last job" after doing it. I assume it would apply to bounties. My point is just that OP is asking about the "Give Cash" option.

Comment: @Sharlike Yes, that's my point exactly.  He's not referring to jobs :)

Answer (score 3):

From an answer by Rockstar Support in the Rockstar Support website post, "[Why can't I give money on GTA online? says "unable to give money" yet I have so much](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200243788-Why-can-t-I-give-money-on-GTA-online-says-unable-to-give-money-yet-I-have-so-much-)":

> It looks like this is a potential bug. Our dev team is now aware and looking into it; thank you for the report.

Comment: @fbueckert I think this was supposed to be a comment in reply to Robotnik from the other answer on this question.

Comment: @kazzamalla That's fine, but this answer doesn't stand by itself at all.  It's up to the original poster to edit the correct link into it.

Comment: @fbueckert Agreed, my point was that this user had no reputation to make a comment and likely having never used the SE network tried to leave the information in a helpful way.  Just pointing it out.

Comment: Yes it was. I was on my phone and didn't know how to add comments